# How to get rid of odd error line when ALT+TAB'ing away from an emacs launched in terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line, emacs

I have a very fresh install of Lucid 10.04 64bit, fully upgraded, and with a raft of additional packages added. Amongst them is `emacs` (23.1+1-4ubuntu7). I habitually launch `emacs` from a terminal.

I just observed that when I have the GUI `emacs` (i.e., the result of running `emacs` not `emacs --nw`) and I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> away from it, each press of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> results in the line

```
** (emacs:7690): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed
```

being output to my terminal window (I assume it's from the stderr of the `emacs` process).

This didn't happen on Jaunty 9.04, for which I had the default Jaunty `emacs` package installed.

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bug is
known](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499),
and there is a work-around in [this comment on
it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499/comments/24).
I effected the change there suggested; once I closed and reopened emacs, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but an easy workaround to this problem is to simply change the theme. The default theme:

```
System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme
```

is set at Ambiance. Changing it to Clearlooks solves the problem (and one could simply customize so that it "looks" like any other theme you like).