# Gdk Gtk warnings and errors from the command line

Tags: themes, gtk

In the newest version of Ubuntu (11.10) when I run from the command line Gtk complains loudly (over several lines) each time a window is opened. The problem is clearly with the theme - if I change the default from `Ambiance` to `High-Contrast` this goes away. Some examples:

```
travis@hydrogen:~$ emacs foo.txt
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(emacs:1550): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

travis@hydrogen:~$ evince test.pdf 
(evince:1566): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: construct property "enable-gestures" for object `EvView' can't be set after construction
(evince:1566): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
(evince:1566): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
(evince:1566): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

I like the themes and I don't want to part with them. How can I fix the command line verbosity from Gtk? I can simply hack the command line to filter out these messages, but I really don't like that idea.

**Possibly Related**

From a previous version: [How to get rid of odd error line...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2341/how-to-get-rid-of-odd-error-line-when-alttabing-away-from-an-emacs-launched-in/4924#4924)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"` messages
 are a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/762167).

To fix it, install the [gtk2-engines-pixbuf](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk2-engines-pixbuf) [image: Install gtk2-engines-pixbuf] package

The warnings you get from running Evince are a separate [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/873866). There isn't a fix for that yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: That bug only seems to reference the first warning from evince, not the `gdk_window_get_pointer` assertion failure.

Comment: @dutchie, that's true.  The gesture warnings are connected to  [bug 873866](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/873866).

Comment: If you are using a 64-bit system, but using 32-bit software producing those warnings you might try: `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386`.

Comment: gtk2-engines-pixbuf have unmet dependencies in Trusty. "gtk2-engines-pixbuf : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed"
How to fix that bug on 14.04?

Comment: To me, this was helpful in relation with IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf` works.