# running evince get error: gdk_window_get_pointer?

Tags: command-line, evince

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gdk Gtk warnings and errors from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line)

Whenever I run evince on terminal, I get this number of the same error messages saying

```
Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

Is it normal? or is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Happens to me also. But it works anyway. Also when running GIMP and EOG from terminal, I always get weird warnings. But just ignore them, if it works, I say.