# I tried to reset unity got some strange output. What to do?

Tags: unity

**I ran:**

`unity --reset`

**And got:**

```
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values

(metacity:3086): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3086): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3086): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3086): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXCreateContext failed
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
abdurahim@abdu-1:~$ 
(metacity:3151): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3151): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3151): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(metacity:3151): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

Before being returned to the prompt.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: The gtk warnings can be removed installing `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` as explained in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/66361/5014).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things, it seems like your 3D support is not enabled.

Somethings you can try are:

- Reboot the system.
- Run `jockey-gtk` and install the drivers for your card.
- Ensure you have all updates installed.

Comment: i ran jockey-gtk and installed the driver all updates are installed and ran unity --reset and getting the same error message again. my laptop is lenovo ideapad Z470

Comment: @Akrahim can you add that info to your question?