# Issues with Quickly: tk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"

Tags: 11.10, command-line, gtk, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gdk Gtk warnings and errors from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line)

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and I decided that I want to learn to develop applications for it. I found some great tutorials, and installed Quickly and started to play around with app development. For some reason though, when I typed in "Quickly create ubuntu-application hello-world" like the tutorial said, the terminal window said the normal 
"Creating project directory hello-world
Creating bzr repository and committing
Launching your newly created project!"
But then said (hello-world:23506): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(hello-world:23506): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(hello-world:23506): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(hello-world:23506): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

The "hello world" application launched seemingly fine after that, but is it a problem? If so, how can I eliminate it? I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a fairly low level error but you should be able to fix this with installing it...

From command line

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

or click the icon here: [gtk2-engines-pixbuf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gtk2-engines-pixbuf) [image: Install gtk2-engines-pixbuf]

Found the solution on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/853232).

Comment: I have a 64bit ubuntu and gtk2-engines-pixbuf had been installed. I had to install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 to dismiss the warning.