# Google Chrome won't Start - Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita"

Tags: gnome, 64-bit, google-chrome, gtk

Google Chrome won't start after a recent `apt-get upgrade`. I can't figure out what I'm missing, and google doesn't turn up many results for these errors:

```
$ google-chrome
[1:1:0518/085616:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[5807:5807:0518/085616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Aborted (core dumped)


$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 42.0.2311.152
```

Chrome was working fine on this machine before the upgrade.

Comment: After installing libexif:i386 with `sudo aptitude install libexif12:i386`, the libexif error goes away. The only remaining errors are GTK theme errors about pixmap and adwaita.

Comment: Based on this question, I was able to fix the pixmap errors: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line.  The only outstanding error message is about the adwaita GTK theme. I have edited the question title to reflect this.

Comment: What is your GTK version? What GTK theme do you use?

Comment: The defaults on Ubuntu Gnome.  My theme is Adwaita, which is the default. `$ dpkg -s libgtk2.0-0|grep '^Version'
Version: 2.24.27-0ubuntu1`

Comment: I should add that this started happening after Chrome was updated: `installed google-chrome-stable:i386 42.0.2311.152-1`

Comment: And why 32-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to only happen with the i386 version of Google Chrome on a 64-bit Ubuntu system. The hint that it was a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem was that installing the `:i386` version of certain packages made some errors go away. I was able to get Chrome working again by installing the 64-bit version:

```
$ sudo aptitude install google-chrome-stable

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libappindicator1 : Conflicts: libappindicator1:i386 but 12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libappindicator1:i386 : Conflicts: libappindicator1 but 12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 google-chrome-stable : Conflicts: google-chrome-stable:i386 but 42.0.2311.152-1 is installed.
 google-chrome-stable:i386 : Conflicts: google-chrome-stable but 42.0.2311.152-1 is to be installed.
 libindicator7 : Conflicts: libindicator7:i386 but 12.10.2+14.10.20140922-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libindicator7:i386 : Conflicts: libindicator7 but 12.10.2+14.10.20140922-0ubuntu1 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     google-chrome-stable:i386   
2)     libappindicator1:i386       
3)     libindicator7:i386          

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I accepted the proposed solution to upgrade several packages to the 64-bit version, and Chrome is working again.

Comment: And what was the reason to install 32-bit Chrome on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Can't remember why I originally did that.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of my answer:

For `GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"`

```
sudo apt-get install  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already done this, as you will see in my comments above. This does fix the "pixmap" errors, but not the other ones. I should add that in my case I had to add `:i386` to the above command: `sudo apt-get install  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386`. This still does not solve the similar problem that arose with adwaita.

Answer (score 1):

Cant always update the application, this worked for me

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard:i386
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard (without the :i386) did though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and mkasberg had the solution- to uninstall 32bit and reinstall 64bit. 
I had gone to google.com/chrome and downloaded the 64bit .deb as normal. I ran the .deb and google-chrome-stable was opened in the Software Center. Installed it, which went fine, but it turns out google-chrome-stable:i386 was installed instead.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable:i386
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a gtk install with prefix `/usr/src/ClawsMail/install`. The above warning is printed after (strace) printing:

```
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/carlo/.gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/src/ClawsMail/install/lib/gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/engines/libadwaita.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Assuming it is normal that nothing is found in my home directory, and because my installation in `/usr/src/ClawsMail/install` is abnormal, I am assuming that normally `libadwaita.so` would be found `<prefix>/lib/gtk-2.0/...`, but that I did not install libadwaita under the same prefix.

HOWEVER - after looking in `/usr/src/ClawsMail/install` it goes on looking in `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/...` so that should not make a difference if the normal install is under `/usr`.

I DO have `libadwaita.so` installed on my system, and well here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.so
```

Note that `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0` doesn't even exist.

It turns out that this search happens during the call to

```
_gtk_find_module (name=0x5555557ee0e0 "adwaita", type=0x7ffff7b0c776 "engines") at gtkmodules.c:196
```

and that the paths searched are those returned by

```
paths = _gtk_get_module_path (type);
```

which gets the three prefixes from

```
gchar **paths = get_module_path();
```

It turns out that the last prefix (`/usr/lib/gtk-2.0`) is dubbed the `pre_multiarch_dir`, aka the prefix before multiarch; which is indeed not used anymore.

My problem is therefore that I do not have the engines installed in the same prefix as where I installed gtk-2.0. However, the search can be extended with environment variables:

If `GTK_EXE_PREFIX` is set then `$GTK_EXE_PREFIX/lib/gtk-2.0` will be used **instead** of the install prefix of gtk-2.0 itself and the pre_multiarch_dir (so not useful on a modern multiarch dist).

If `GTK_PATH` is set then that will be used on top of everything else. I believe the latter can even be a semicolon separated list of paths.

Using

```
export GTK_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0"
```

therefore, made the warning go away for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Kubuntu 20.04 this worked for me (had this error when trying to run JavaFX app):

```
sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this annoying warning/error for a long time, on one of my CentOS-7 boxes.  (Probably same reason for Ubuntu, I expect).

Finally tracked it down today.  In the Gtk-2.0 directory, the dynamic lib file: "libadwaita.so" was missing. I would get this warning message, everytime I started a Gnome/X11 window application:

Gtk-WARNING **: ... Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita"

The "libadwaita.so" file has to be placed into directory:

/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines

The theme "adwaita" appears to be the Gnome default, and in some earlier Gnome installs, the dynamic lib file was just not getting dropped into the right location.  On the machine which gave the warning-error, I only had two files:  "liboxygen-gtk.so" and "libpixmap.so", whereas the no-problem box had all three lib files.  I resolved the warning-error message by simply copying the correct "libadwaita.so" lib to the above Gtk-2.0 "engines" directory.  No other changes needed.  Note: I had all the Gnome themes, engines and so on, installed, with latest versions.  Linux kernel is 4.4.185-1.

I have just built a Glade/GTK-2.0 application, using C, and two instances of this annoying warning-error would appear, every time it was started.  Everything worked ok, but the warning-error would pop-up on the invoking xterm window in bright-yellow highlighted text, which made it appear there was a problem with my application, so I had to track down this issue today.  Hope this info helps.